# Crashlytics + Jira integration. Failed to verify credentials (400)

Tags: firebase, jira, crashlytics, firebase-console

I'm trying to integrate jira with firebase by this guide https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9118259?hl=en but I'm unable to setup the integration.

1. Entered jira project URL as `https://[workspace-name].atlassian.net/projects/[project-key]`
2. Entered email
3. Entered JIRA token
4. Click on `Verify & Save`

Progress appears and nothing. I checked chrome console and I see failed request to `https://firebaseextensions-pa.clients6.google.com/v1/service_provider_values`
Request body contains data from form (url, email, token). Response is

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I would expect mighty Google to show a specific error message for this...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I contacted Firebase support and we found that the reason is required/mandatory fields of 'Bug' issue at my Jira project. Firebase will provide only summary and description of issue so if you have additional required filed like Environment or custom field then firebase will not setup integration with Jira.

"Unfortunately, if you have a custom field that's marked as required or mandatory, we won't be able to fill it on your behalf."

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem.

Comment: To add onto this for any international people in here, if your Jira instance is in a language that is not english, and this answer didn't work for you -- changing the name of the issue type in Jira to actually be "Bug" is also necessary.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR;
You have 2 options to get rid of this Error.

1. Make all the items/custom items in your JIRA Project's 'Bug' Issue Optional (https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Making-Custom-field-required-and-optional/qaq-p/1974194).
2. Setup Automation to provide default values for Mandatory Fields(https://support.atlassian.com/jira-cloud-administration/docs/configure-a-custom-field/).